# I can't connect my HTML form with MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to build a form, and then connect it to my SQL database to fill a table, using PHP. But I can't connect the database. When I press commit, then a blank page is open.. And nothing is inserted into my database. Please can you help me? What is the problem?

Here is my HTML form

```
<html>
 <head>
      <title> Futja e te dhenave nepermjet nje forme </title>
            <style type = "text/css">
         body  { background-color: #cfd0f9 }
         h2    { font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                 color: blue }
        h3     {font-color: yellow}

          .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
   </head>
<body>

<h1><center>please enter data</center></h1>

<p> <span class="error">* please fill these fields.</span> </p>
<form method="post" action="insert.php">

  <strong> Emri:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </strong> <input type="text" name="fname" />
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
   <br>

   <strong> Mbiemri:&nbsp &nbsp </strong> <input type="text" name="lname" />
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $dtlErr;?></span>
   <br>


<input type="submit" name= "shto" value="Add"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the `insert.php`. My database is called `test`, and the table is called `user`. The table has three columns: `User_id, fname,lname`

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('The connection is not possible: ' . mysql_error());
  }


if(empty($_POST['fname']))
die ('Name is empty'. mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
if(empty($_POST['lname']))
die ('Last name is empty'. mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO user(fname,lname)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Successful insertion!!! ";

mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try mysqli_ functions maybe your hosting provider has update php to a version that doesn't accept mysql_ functions

Comment: Do you have a proper server for your php development...do you have the folder placed in your www or htdocs folder?

Comment: You should never insert user input directly into the DB and you really should use MYSQLI_ or better yet PDO as MYSQL_ has been depreciated.

Comment: Also use `$_POST["fname"]` instead `$_POST[fname]`. Same goes to $_POST[lname]

Comment: i dont have server.. I am trying my page at local host http://localhost:8181/   thats the reason i have put te adress 127.0.0.1

Comment: That doesn't matter you state that you get a blank page same would apply if your test server is running one of the newer versions of php. I see that you have set error messages from php for connection trouble. Have you looked if you have HTML source content?

Comment: I would assume that the field called `User_id` is a key and therefore would need to be included in the `INSERT` statement i.e. `INSERT INTO user(User_id,fname,lname) VALUES ($User_id, '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]')` check the screen or the `php_error.log` for errors.

Comment: It would then most likely be an auto increment value. So no need to fill in when you insert a new row.

Comment: @Mr.Radical, yes it is a autoincrement..so it is no need to fill it. And if I insert html content in insert.php the html content appears, but the database is not fielled till

Comment: @RiggsFolly at php_errr.log there is no error for these date...The screen does not have errors too...What can I do?

Comment: maybe you forgot to add brackets after if statement.

Comment: Sorry I ask but in which if?

Comment: add a { after last ) of IF test and closing } after line with die... ;

Comment: @user3272713 is you question solved? If so could you please upvote / accept an answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some messages so you know where the code has got to like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
    echo '<pre>Before Connect' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>'; // display the $_POST array

    $con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
    if (!$con)
    {
       die('The connection is not possible: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo 'After Connect';

    mysql_select_db('test', $con);    

    echo 'Database selected';

    if(empty($_POST['fname'])) die ('Name is empty'. mysql_error());

    if(empty($_POST['lname'])) die ('Last name is empty'. mysql_error());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(fname,lname) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

    echo "<br>$sql</br>";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Successful insertion!!! ";

    mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if you dont get anything to the screen, something is very seriously wrong. Remember the `die()` commands should write to the browser as well.

Comment: when i execute this the all the code of index.php appears on the screen that before was blank...I dont know why...I am getting crazy..plese help me

Comment: That was a change for the `insert.php` not `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Final Edit:

```
<html>
<head><title>Insert</title></head>
<body>    
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['fname']))    
        {
        echo ('<b>Name is empty!</b>');
        }
    elseif(!isset($_POST['lname']))
        {
        echo ('<b>Name is empty!</b>');
        }
    else {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname']; 


    $con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('The connection is not possible: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO user(fname,lname) VALUES('".$fname."','".$lname."')";

    if (!mysql_db_query($con, $sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo ('<b>Successful insertion!!!</b>');

    mysql_close($con);

    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed multiple lines of your code. Especially the `die()` and `mysql_error()` the mysql_error did not apply because you were do doing anything with you server at that point in you code. Some of the other comments on your code can be found in my initial answer. I have included it in my answer for reference.

Old version:

Change:

```
if(empty($_POST['fname'])) 
die ('Name is empty'. mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test", $con); if(empty($_POST['lname'])) 
die ('Last name is empty'. mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
```

into:

```
if(empty($_POST['fname'])){ 
die ('Name is empty'. mysql_error());
} 
mysql_select_db("test", $con); 
if(empty($_POST['lname'])){ 
die ('Last name is empty'. mysql_error());
} 
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
```

I have added brackets for IF statement.

Add ; after `mysql_close($con)` like so `mysql_close($con);`